# Windows Scheduler doesn't save excel file

Tags: excel, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I have a vb script that runs correctly when executed on the command line or double clicked. The script opens an excel file, runs a macro, saves the file, and then closes the file. When I try to set up a Windows Scheduler though, the script doesn't save the excel file. Instead, it just outputs it to a text file in my User/AppData/Local/Temp folder. Why isn't it saving over the original excel file and how can I make it do just that instead of the text file in my Temp folder?

Edit: I have looked into why but can't find anything that would work or explain why.

---

```
'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\UserID\Desktop\TestingVB4.xlsm"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath = "Module1.Testing1"

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = False 'or "True"

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
  wb.Save

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close 

'Reset Display Alerts Before Closing
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit

'Leaves an onscreen message!
  MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation
```

---

Comment: Relevant [Excel Macro creates .tmp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58083069)

Comment: Try commenting out the `msgbox` part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) instead since you have the file name. This should force it to save to the correct file instead of a temp file:

`wb.SaveAs ExcelFilePath`

Comment: Not sure that will make a difference, it's likely because an AV program is reading the temp file at it's creation so excel can't remove it and save the changes to the original file. See [Description of the Way That Excel Saves Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814068/description-of-the-way-that-excel-saves-files).

Comment: So I changed a setting in the scheduler from user can be logged on or off to just logged on and it works correctly now. Though I need it to be running when logged off